# I want to add an element to a list from a map in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api

I have a list model class name previous loan. I want to add loanOutstanding value in previousLoan Model if its key has matched. How can I do this?

```
"prevLoans": [
{
"id": 200855,
"disbursementDate": "2018-10-09",
"lastInstallmentDate": "2022-01-10",
"loanCompletedDate": "0000-00-00",
"loanAmount": 70000
},{
"id": 345855,
"disbursementDate": "2018-10-09",
"lastInstallmentDate": "2022-01-10",
"loanCompletedDate": "0000-00-00",
"loanAmount": 70000
},{
"id": 965821,
"disbursementDate": "2018-10-09",
"lastInstallmentDate": "2022-01-10",
"loanCompletedDate": "0000-00-00",
"loanAmount": 70000
},
],

"loanOutstanding": {
"200855": 21379
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I found out from your explanation, and your Map, i added { } to your Map because your map is not complete in my idea:

```
  var loansMap ={
    "prevLoans": [
      {
        "id": 200855,
        "disbursementDate": "2018-10-09",
        "lastInstallmentDate": "2022-01-10",
        "loanCompletedDate": "0000-00-00",
        "loanAmount": 70000
      },{
        "id": 345855,
        "disbursementDate": "2018-10-09",
        "lastInstallmentDate": "2022-01-10",
        "loanCompletedDate": "0000-00-00",
        "loanAmount": 70000
      },{
        "id": 965821,
        "disbursementDate": "2018-10-09",
        "lastInstallmentDate": "2022-01-10",
        "loanCompletedDate": "0000-00-00",
        "loanAmount": 70000
      },
    ],

    "loanOutstanding": {
      "200855": 21379
    },
  };
```

here is the code to put 21379 as a value of loanOutstanding key in prevLoans Model:

```
    for (var loan in loansMap['prevLoans'] as List) {
      final id = loan['id'].toString();
      if ((loansMap['loanOutstanding'] as Map).containsKey(id)) {
        loan['loanOutstanding'] = (loansMap['loanOutstanding'] as Map)[id];
      }
    }

    print('loans: ${loansMap}');
```

here is the print result:

```
 loans: {
prevLoans: [
{
id: 200855, 
disbursementDate: 2018-10-09, 
lastInstallmentDate: 2022-01-10, 
loanCompletedDate: 0000-00-00, 
loanAmount: 70000, 
loanOutstanding: 21379
}, 
{
id: 345855, 
disbursementDate: 2018-10-09, 
lastInstallmentDate: 2022-01-10,
loanCompletedDate: 0000-00-00, 
loanAmount: 70000
}, 
{
id: 965821, 
disbursementDate: 2018-10-09, 
lastInstallmentDate: 2022-01-10, 
loanCompletedDate: 0000-00-00, 
loanAmount: 70000
}
], 
loanOutstanding: {200855: 21379}
}
```

as you see `loanOutstanding: 21379` added.
if some of the structured changed is because you haven't added clear map in your explanation.

but if you have any question or help i'm here ;)

happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

After parsing the json, you can iterate over the loan list and modify the matched one:

```
for (final loan in loans) {
  final id = loan['id'].toString();
  if (outstandings.containsKey(id)) {
    loan['loanOutstanding'] = outstandings[id]!;
  }
}
```